# Should security concerns be present in the domain model?

Tags: .net, security, mvvm, domain-driven-design

I'm working on a Winforms project (.NET 4) that is based loosely on MVVM.  For security, the application authenticates against Active Directory and then uses role based security to determine access permissions to different parts of the program.  Security is implemented with the PrincipalPermissionAttribute in most places, like so:

```
<PrincipalPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Role:="Managers")> _
Public Sub Save() Implements IProductsViewModel.Save
    mUOW.Commit()
End Sub
```

As you can probably tell from the Interface implementation, this specific Sub is in a ViewModel.  The PrincipalPermissionAttribute is checking to see if the current user (Thread.CurrentPrincipal) is in the Manager role.

Which leads to my question:  Should security checks (such as above) be done in the Domain Model?

I have two conflicting views when thinking about it myself:

1) Keep the domain model ignorant of as many other concerns as you can to reduce complexity and dependency. (Keep security out, perhaps implemented in ViewModel).

2) The domain model is, in a way, the place where "the buck stops here."  If I implement security in the domain model, then I know that even if security in another layer fails, the domain model should catch it.

So, what say ye, security in the domain model or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I find this concern seems to belong in the service layer.  Presumably, the application will persist through the service layer to one degree or another in order to reach the domain, and you could easily have a non-domain service to verify the user's role prior to the commit.

The reason that I would do it in this fashion is based on the theory that the closer you get to the core of the domain, the more expensive the call stack has become.  Preventing abuse / misuse of the domain at a higher level means better responsiveness and cohesiveness.

Additionally, assume that the requirement changes, whereas someone in another role can now do the same operation.  Maintaining these all in the service layer means that you are also not changing code that should be churning less often.  At least in what I have done, the positive takeaway from this is that the closer to the core you get, the less likely code is to change.  This means that you also reduce the change of your change to "ripple" to other areas that you did not intend.

On a broader concern, and nothing personal, I do not like the idea of putting data access of any sort in the ViewModel.  The ViewModel is intended to be a representation of the model, specific to an implementation.  These objects should be, ideally, as lightweight as possible.  If a change is made to a product, for example, the change would go through the service, then to the repository, where it could be registered with the unit of work, awaiting to be committed.

Comment: Some very good arguments for keeping security out of the domain, thanks.  As for the data access in the ViewModel, I understand where you are coming from and agree.  I'm using EF 4 and my UOW is really just a wrapper around an ObjectContext.  I use a "UOW per ViewModel" approach, e.g. when the View requests a new ViewModel, the ViewModel brings along a UOW that was created when the repository pulled the entities.  Any changes made by the ViewModel are automagically tracked by the UOW.  The only thing the ViewModel can do with the UOW is tell it to commit.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 kinds of security.

One which is purely technical - something like "all traffic should go through https" or "only specific service should touch database" or "only specific process should be able to touch file system/registry".

Second which is tied up with domain. Something like "only user with role Secretary can access payment history" or "unauthorized users should not be able to access accounting stuff".

First one should be decoupled from domain. Second one should live inside domain.

Comment: Great answer, I think this is where I was going in my original thinking.  How do you protect read-only operations that may not have a true domain representation such as reporting when following this methodology?  Do you have a "report" entity, or do you protect it at some other level?

Comment: I would have UserRights CanSeeReports which would be used for authorization by process that is responsible for showing it. Would be better if Report itself knew about how to represent itself - that way Report could always ensure authorization. But I'm ok with this loss of isolation.

Comment: When you say domain, do you mean the domain model, for example the "Order" class, or do you mean a security service which can valididate if the current user has certain permissions ? I agree that in certain cases the security service will not have enough information in which case the responsibility lies with the domain

Comment: @Sudarshan classes or services don't define what's your domain. ideas do.

Comment: I agree, my question was a little more technical though, does the responsibility lie with the "domain model layer" or the application layer, think in terms of a layered architecture

Answer (score 0):

Great answers here. I guess it depends on the level of granularity your permission system has. Let's say we are designing a "Task Management System" and we want users to limit visiblity on a "Project" level.

- We could design one generic "can-read" role or permission which is addressed to all projects.
- We could go deeper and implement a DAC-like system, where we want to answer the question "can this user read this particular object". This means that each "Project" has its own "Read-Permission", therefore not allowing us to implement other than at the domain-level (or very close above)